# Is there a pre-existing WinAPI to check if some_app.exe can run w/o providing full-path and running it at any point

Tags: winapi

Is there a pre-existing WinAPI to check if `some_app.exe` can run w/o providing full-path and running it at any point?

For example, let's say I want to run `cmd.exe` or `git.exe`, but I don't provide with full path . Before I run it, is it possible of me to know prematurely if I can run it without knowing its full path?

One idea that comes to my mind is to emulate the way Windows does it, i.e. to check the current path, then to iterate through `%PATH%` variable and so on, but is there perhaps a  Winapi for this exact purpose?

Comment: [`SearchPath`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processenv/nf-processenv-searchpathw).

Comment: @ RbMm Searchpath seems to be designed to simply search for files. I try to find a way to determine the path to the executable executed via CMD or CTRL+R

Comment: when you pass 0 in place *lpApplicationName*  - the **exactly** `SearchPathW` function used for expand name in first *lpCommandLine* token for full path. so `SearchPathW` is exactly solution here

Comment: [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processenv/nf-processenv-searchpathw) doesn't mention `lpApplicationName`. Did you mean `lpFileName` instead? P.S. also would you like to write up an answer, for score + more organised discussion?

Comment: i mean [*lpApplicationName*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessw) from `CreateProcessW` api. if you pas not 0 *lpApplicationName* it used. if you no - the `SearchPathW` used for get full path.

Comment: Unfortunately, the premise of my question is that I wanna find out a way to find a full-path to some executable before ever running it. Suppose I wanna find out what would be the path to some `virus.exe` without ever running it or knowing its full path. `CreateProcessW`, the best I understand, yields the app to get executed

Comment: again - this way - use `SearchPath`

Comment: You weaseled over a vital detail. *"Before I run it, is it possible of me to know prematurely if I can run it"*. What's *"it"*? Anyway, this is an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info). What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Apologies for the possible ambiguity. Suppose you have `git.exe` that you consider launching, but you don't want to run it straight away. Perhaps you want to find out if your machine has `git.exe`, without running it just yet. Is there a WinAPI s.t. if I input `git.exe`, it would output `C:\Program Files\Git\bin\``, i.e. the full path that is used in cmd or Ctrl+R , when you just type in `git.exe`

Comment: Why won't you listen to @RbMm? He has given you the answer.

Comment: *exe* can exec only via *CreateProcessW* (except subsystem native case). if you pass full or partial path to *exe* (via 1-st parameter) it used. if no - system take first token from command line (2-nd parameter) and try expand it to full path via `SearchPath`. if file found this way - this path and used. if no - error (file/path not found returned)

Comment: It also depends very much on what you mean by "run". Call `CreateProcess`? Invoke from the Windows Run dialog? Execute a shell verb?

Comment: When calling `SearchPath()`, if you set its `lpPath` to NULL then it searches for the specified `lpFileName` in the current working directory and the system search path.  The exact same thing that happens when you run an EXE without specifying its path.

Comment: `git.exe` is just an arbitrary image name. *Any* executable image can be called `git.exe`. It seems like you want to find out, whether a *particular* application is installed in the system, but you are asking how to find out, if there is *any* file with a given pattern. That's called the [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info).

Comment: @ IInspectable , It is all good, as for the scope of this question, I presume that `git.exe` is the correct `git.exe` I look for. Windows-specific programming is unsurprisingly specific, and I understand that if I look up, say, `git.exe`, it might prioritise some `git.exe` in `C:/Windows` over `C:\Program Files\Git\bin`. In fact, come to think of it, Windows prioritises .PIF files over .EXE

Answer (score 1):

@RbMm has already pointed out the solution: Use [SearchPath](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processenv/nf-processenv-searchpathw) API.

The following is an example (a console application) of how to use that API, you can refer to.

```
#include <windows.h>

#define BUF_SIZE 260

int main()
{
    WCHAR appFullPath[BUF_SIZE];
    DWORD result = SearchPath(NULL, L"git.exe",NULL, BUF_SIZE, appFullPath, NULL);
    if(result == 0)
        wprintf(L"SearchPath call get an error: %d \n", GetLastError());

    wprintf(L"App full path: %s \n", appFullPath);
    getchar();
}
```

The output of above code:

[image]

Comment: Han , kinda a silly question, but how do I compile the code provided? Is it in Microsoft C of some sort?

Comment: @tabdiukov I compile the code in Visual Studio 2017. Make sure the [Windows SDK](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-10-sdk) installed on your developing machine.